# Problema en formar matrices para una permutación

Tags: python, matrices

Quiero hacer permutaciones de números sin usar `numpy` o algún modulo si es posible, y ya encontré la solución a ello usando matrices:

Número de ejemplo:

```
num = 123
```

Yendo de izquierda a derecha y aumentando un dígito por la izquierda la vez por cada pasada:

```
[[1]] 
__
[[2, 1],
 [1, 2]]
__
[[3, 2, 1],
 [3, 1, 2],
 [2, 3, 1],
 [1, 3, 2],
 [2, 1, 3],
 [1, 2, 3]]
```

Como ven, las combinaciones previas (antes de las rayas), se repiten de nuevo, pero agregándoles el siguiente dígito en orden de izquierda a derecha, en cada fila de la matriz anterior, y avanza una columna a la vez hasta que llega al final de la matriz.

Es en el código de Python donde tengo el problema, lo haría en 2 funciones, aquí la primera:

```
def ma_num_orden(m, a):
    largo = len(m[0])
    columnas = largo + 1
    filas = factorial(largo)
    matriz_final = []
    for i in range(columnas):
        matriz = m.copy()
        for j in range(filas):
            matriz[j].insert(i, a)
        matriz_final += matriz
    return matriz_final
```

El código toma una matriz `m`, por ejemplo `m = [[2, 1], [1, 2]]`, y le agrega un número adicional a, resultando en `[[3, 2, 1], [3, 1, 2], [2, 3, 1], [1, 3, 2], [2, 1, 3], [1, 2, 3]]`, o eso es lo que debería resultar; el problema que tengo radica en la linea 7:

```
matriz = m.copy()
```

Necesito usar la matriz m original y copiarla en cada loop (`for k in range(filas):`), pero al modificar la matriz con `insert`, se modifica tanto la matriz matriz como la matriz `m`, tenía entendido que la función `m.copy()` realizaba una copia independiente de `m`, para tener libertad de modificar la matriz, sin que `m` sea modificado, pero eso no ocurre, la matriz `m` se modifica de la misma forma que matriz lo hace, ya intente usar `splicing m[:], copy.copy(m) y list(m)`, pero es lo mismo.

El código funciona si hago esto:

```
def ma_num_orden(m, a):
    largo = len(m[0])
    columnas = largo + 1
    filas = factorial(largo)
    matriz_final = []
    for i in range(columnas):
        matriz = [[2, 1], [1, 2]]
        for j in range(filas):
            matriz[j].insert(i, a)
        matriz_final += matriz
    return matriz_final


m = [[2, 1], [1, 2]]

x = ma_num_order(m, 3)

print(x)
```

Pero ese no es el punto, ya que la función `ma_num_orden(m, a)` recibirá las matrices previas que generó, es decir, recibirá diferentes matrices que serán generados, no puedo darle manualmente la matriz.

Ahora mi pregunta, ¿Hay alguna forma de trabajar la matriz `m` y la matriz matriz de manera independiente? es lo único que me falta por solucionar.

Comment: Respuesta breve: debes usar _deepcopy()_ en vez de _copy()_. Esta funcionalidad la tienes en el módulo `copy` que debes importar. (`matriz = copy.deepcopy(m)`. La respuesta larga, por supuesto, sería ¿cuál es la diferencia entre ambas? ¿Por qué hay que usar deepcopy()? Si te interesa puedo extenderme

Comment: WOw, gracias pro la respuesta, con ello ya funciona; co respecto a lo de extenderte, me gustaría saber por que no funcionó las otras alternativas y si esta, si no es mucha molestia :D.

Comment: @GiancarloAguirre  evita colocar los lenguajes de programación en los títulos ya que para eso estan las etiquetas, por otro lado colocar "Principiante" no aporta nada por lo que es considerado ruido,  asi que no lo coloques.

Answer (score 7):

Respuesta breve: debes usar `deepcopy()` en vez de `copy()`. Esta funcionalidad la tienes en el módulo `copy` que debes importar, para después hacer `matriz = copy.deepcopy(m)`.

La respuesta larga, por supuesto, sería ¿cuál es la diferencia entre ambas? ¿Por qué hay que usar `deepcopy()`? Respira hondo que nos zambullimos.

### Un poco de teoría antes

Lo primero, en python **todo** son referencias. Lo que en C serían punteros.

Lo que esto quiere decir, es que una variable como por ejemplo `m` es en realidad un *apuntador* que señala a una zona de la memoria donde realmente están los datos. Supongamos que los datos son una lista:

```
m = []
```

Esto crea un objeto de tipo `list` en memoria, inicialmente vacío, y deja a `m` *apuntando* a esa lista vacía. Es decir, esto:

[image: Lista vacia]

Si ahora metemos dentro de `m` un par de números, por ejemplo así:

```
m.append(1)
m.append(2)
```

se crearán dos objetos de tipo `int`, uno con el valor `1` y otro con el valor  `2` y en `m` se almacenarán las correspondientes referencias (apuntadores) a esos datos. Es decir, esto:

[image]

¿Qué ocurre si intentas cambiar el 1 por un 10, por ejemplo, mediante una asignación como esta?

```
m[0] = 10
```

Contrariamente a lo que quizás esperarías, no se modifica la caja que tenía un 1 para que ahora tenga un 10, sino que se crea un nuevo objeto `int` con el valor 10, y se modifica la referencia `m[0]` para que en lugar de apuntar al 1, apunte al 10. Es decir, la cosa queda así:

[image: Asignación]

Ese objeto `1` que ha quedado "descolgado" será borrado enseguida por el recolector de basura de Python, no nos preocupemos por él.

### Copiar listas (mal)

Un intento simplista de copiar la lista mediante una asignación como la siguiente:

```
matriz = m
```

lo único que hace en realidad es crear una segunda referencia llamada `matriz` que apuntará a **la misma lista**, es decir, tendremos esto:

[image: matriz]

Ya que `m` y `matriz` se refieren en realidad al mismo dato (eso se puede comprobar con la comparación `m is matriz` que daría `True`  en este caso), resulta que si cambiamos de valor a `m[1]`, estaremos cambiando también `matriz[1]`

### Copiar listas (mejor)

Una mejora es usar `m.copy()` o `m[:]` que hace lo mismo. En ambos casos se crea una copia de `m` y se retorna la referencia a la nueva copia. De modo que si hacemos:

```
matriz = m.copy()
```

la situación será ahora:

[image: copy]

Vemos que la copia crea una lista nueva. `matriz` y `m` ya no se refieren al mismo objeto (ahora `m is matriz` dará `False`). No obstante, las *referencias* que hay dentro de `matriz` apuntan a los mismos datos que las referencias que había en `m` (es decir `m[0] is matriz[0]` sí será `True`). De paso he eliminado al 1 que ya no pintaba nada.

Si imprimes `m` o `matriz` en ambos casos se verá `[10, 2]`, por lo que todo parece normal y parece que la copia ha sido un éxito.

De hecho, estas copias son independientes en el "primer nivel", aunque comparten el "segundo nivel", por así decir. Pero esto no suele ser problema y pasa completamente desapercibido, ya que si ahora hago por ejemplo:

```
matriz[1] = 100
```

y luego imprimo `matriz`, veré `[10,100]`, pero si imprimo `m` seguiré viendo `[10, 2]`. Es decir, modificar una no afecta a la otra. Y esto es porque la asignación que acabo de hacer causa esta situación:

[image: reasignar]

## Problema con `copy()`

El problema aparece si los valores guardados en `m`, en lugar de ser enteros como en el ejemplo previo, son a su vez otras listas, como por ejemplo:

```
m = [[1,2], [3,4]]
```

En este caso la figura sería:

[image: Listas en listas]

Vemos que el primer elemento de `m` es una referencia que apunta a otra lista, cuyos elementos son referencias que apuntan a los enteros `1` y `2`, y análogamente el segundo elemento de `m`.

Una copia normal como la que antes hicimos:

```
matriz = m.copy()
```

crea una nueva lista, cuyos contenidos son copias de la lista original, es decir, serán referencias a las **mismas sublistas**. Así:

[image: Copy de listas en listas]

Buff! La figura se está complicando. Te animo a dibujarla tú mismo en un papel y ver qué pasa si ahora haces `m[0][0] = 10`. Si te fijas con cuidado, verás que eso cambia la primera referencia de la primera sublista, para que deje de apuntar al 1 y pase a apuntar a un `10`. ¡Pero eso indirectamente cambiará el valor de `matriz[0][0]` (aunque no el de `matriz[0]` que sigue apuntando a la misma sublista.

## Deepcopy

La función `copy.deepcopy()` es similar a `copy()`, pero no se detiene en el primer nivel. Si el objeto que está copiando contiene referencias a otros objetos mutables (otras listas), crea copias también de éstas, hasta cualquier nivel de profundidad, deteniéndose sólo cuando encuentra un objeto de tipo inmutable, como un `int`.

Por tanto, tras hacer:

```
matriz = copy.deepcopy(m)
```

tendremos

[image: deepcopy]

en la que te animo a intentar visualizar qué ocurre si hago `m[0][0]=10`. Comprobarás que eso no cambiará la referencia en `matriz[0][0]` que seguirá apuntando a `1`.

Si has conseguido seguirme hasta aquí (si no, puedes volver a leerlo más despacio haciendo tus propios gráficos), ya puedes quitarte el calificativo "principiante" :-)

Comment: No hace falta graficar, ya entendí :D, el problema era que el copy() solo copia una sola capa, por lo tanto no funcionará con sublistas, mientras deepcopy copiara más a fondo hasta que encuentre un objeto inmutable, gracias por la explicación, fué muy interesante :D.